# Xcode Change View when app is in the backgorund

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, background, appdelegate

I'm building an app with a "locked" folder (locked view) inside of it, and i wanted to know how can I change the view when the app is in the background.
what I want is that every time the user press the home button, the app will return for the "asking for password" view.

my problem is that I dont know how to segue to this view through the `didEnterBackground` method in the AppDelegate

thanks for any help!

Comment: You can have your view controllers subscribe to the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackground` notification and invoke a modal segue to your enter password screen - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862614/uiapplicationdidenterbackgroundnotification

Answer (score 0):

You can not customize the Home Button. When the user presses the home button from inside your app, he will always go to the home screen (springboard). There is no way to change this with public APIs. If you somehow manage to achieve that goal, your app will certainly not be accepted by the itunes store. And I don't know of any private APIs which would allow this. I don't think this is possible on a non-jailbroken device. It may be possible on a jailbroken device if your app has root powers.

Comment: I think the OP meant that their app will ask for a password when the user returns to it after pressing the home button, not instead of returning to Springboard when the home button is pressed

Comment: oh, you mean the iPhone 5S fingerprint home button press that unlocks the device?

Comment: No, I think they mean they want their app to prompt the user for a password when it resumes from the background - I.e. When the app is backgrounded, it is effectively "locked" when the user returns to that app

Comment: ok, i think i will delete my answer soon... it's just very unclear to me what the OP wants

Comment: yes it's not what i meant, when i said "home button" i meant when the user closes the app and then return to it

Comment: So.. just follow the link in the comment from Paulw11 about `UIApplicationDidEnterBackground`... it will help you